# Univocity parsers / Required validation (NotNull)

Tags: validation, univocity

I'm using the fixed length parser to import files and java beans with annotations as mapping classes.
How can I define a field as required? Couldn't find an annotation.
Could I implement a custom converter for such a validation?

Comment: Hi @Peter, you can now use the `@Validate` annotation. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Version 2.7.0 introduces the `@Validate` annotation. By default it disallows null or blank values.

Use it like this:

```
public static class A {
    @Parsed(index = 0)
    @Validate(nullable = true)
    public String nullNotBlank;

    @Parsed(index = 1)
    @Validate(oneOf = {"a", "b"})
    public String aOrB;

    @Parsed(index = 2)
    @Validate(oneOf = {"a"}, noneOf = "b")
    public String aNotB;

    @Parsed(index = 3)
    @Validate(allowBlanks = true, oneOf = {"a", "b"})
    public String aOrBOrNull;
}
```

Another way would be to put the annotation in your setter method.

```
@Parsed
public void setMyField(String data) {
    if(data == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("MyField can't be null");
    }
    this.myField = data;
}
```

If you have this requirement for many different fields, you can create a custom conversion. I've [updated the tutorial](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) yesterday so have look there.

More specifically, check the [Using your own conversions in annotations](https://www.univocity.com/pages/java_beans.html#using-your-own-conversions-in-annotations) section of the tutorial.

To avoid repeating adding such annotation everywhere refer to section [Avoiding repetitive annotations](https://www.univocity.com/pages/java_beans.html#avoiding-repetitive-annotations) in the same page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear about your plans for future versions. For now I use annotations provided by java bean validation in a second step for each converted bean.

Comment: @peter the latest version has the Validate annotation now. Hope it works well for you.

Comment: Hi @Jeronimo, yes it works well, using the latest 2.7.1 version. Could you also add a regex pattern to Validate annotation? What do you think about defining a validationClass (similar to Convert)? Should I use Java BeanValidation for that? Thanks

Comment: @Peter version 2.7.3 supports regex and you can also define multiple custom validation implementation. Hope it works well for you.